# NoMethodError in MicropostsController#create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nomethoderror

I've run into an issue with my Ruby on Rails app. I've a page called /discussion which contains discussions that users can comment on with microposts.  The goal here is to have a form below each micropost that, when submitted, will put the text in the discussion.  The form shows up - but whenever I click submit I get the error:

```
NoMethodError in MicropostsController#create

undefined method `micropost' for #<User:0x007f9744091680>
Rails.root: /home/nick/Documents/RailsProjects/buon

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
app/controllers/microposts_controller.rb:8:in `create'
```

---

### the micropost controller

```
class MicropostsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :signed_in_user, only: [:create, :destroy]

  def index
  end

  def create
    @micropost = current_user.micropost.build(params[:micropost])
     if @micropost.save
       flash[:success] = "Posted!"
       redirect_to root_url
     else
       render 'static_pages/home'
     end
  end

  def destroy
  end
end
```

---

### the _discusions.html

```
<% content_for :script do %>
<%= javascript_include_tag 'hover_content' %>
<% end %>

<li>
  <div class = "intro-bar"><span class = "intro"><%=discussion.intro %></span></div>
  <div class = "content-bar"><span class = "content"><%= discussion.content %></span></div>
  <span class = "timestamp">
    Posted <%= time_ago_in_words(discussion.created_at) %> ago.
  </span>
</li>
<% if signed_in? %>
<div class = "row">
  <aside class = "span4">
    <section>
      <%= render 'shared/micropost_form', :locals => {:discussion => discussion }%>
    </section>
  </aside>
</div>
<% end %>
```

---

### the micropost model

```
class Micropost < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :break_votes, :content, :not_votes
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :discussion


  validates :content, presence: true, length: { maximum: 200 }
  validates :user_id, presence: true
  default_scope order: 'microposts.created_at DESC'
end
```

---

any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

If this is a `has_many` association you need to pluralize, so your code should read:

```
@micropost = current_user.microposts.build(params[:micropost])
```

Comment: that worked!  Thanks so much! now i believe the micropost has gotten through, i just need to get it to display the microposts below the discussion.  I imagine that would entail a list of rendered microposts in the _discussion.html but how exactly would i go about doing that?

Comment: Look at the second code example under [6.7: Listing all posts](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html#listing-all-posts) in the rails getting started guide. You will want to do do that, only your loop should be `<% discussion.microposts.each do |micropost| %>'.

Comment: I put 

<% discussion.microposts.each do |micropost| %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= micropost.content%></td>
    </tr>
    <% end %>

into _discussions below the first <li> and its still now showing up

Comment: Are you sure that the `Discussion` you're looking at has `Microposts` associated with it? You're not validating the presence of a `discussion_id` in your `Micropost` model and none of the code you posted explicitly sets one.

Comment: when i add the line validates :discussion_id, presence: true I get an error message saying NoMethodError in Microposts#create

Showing /home/nick/Documents/RailsProjects/buon/app/views/shared/_discussion_form.html.erb where line #1 raised:

undefined method `model_name' for NilClass:Class

Comment: @user2472006 You should mark this answer as accepted and create a new question which includes the partial that raises the error.